# How to set dynamic form on popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a dynamic form the code is following:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://vd263.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/60dfa9fa31db677b87c9061c53d0925b" class="infusion-form" method="POST">
    <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="60dfa9fa31db677b87c9061c53d0925b" />
    <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="Sign up for newsletter" />
    <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.44.0.47" />
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_Email">Email *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vd263.infusionsoft.com/app/webTracking/getTrackingCode?trackingId=d611bf89e5e09e0678e6bf94789f54a0"></script>
```

I want to show it on popup in wordpress but the issue is they are not supporting javascript I am using the Ninja popup and Popup Builder. Please suggest me any plugin who support this or would I have to create my own popup.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has built in routines that enqueue javascript and css, so it is best to insert something like the below into your theme's function.php

```
function ninja_popup_add_extra_css_and_js() {

    wp_register_script('extra_javascript', "https://vd263.infusionsoft.com/app/webTracking/getTrackingCode?trackingId=d611bf89e5e09e0678e6bf94789f54a0" ,null,  TRUE);  //change  null  to  array('jquery') if the javascript depends upon jquery
    wp_enqueue_script('extra_javascript');

    wp_register_style( 'extra_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my_extra.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'extra_css' );    
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ninja_popup_add_extra_css_and_js');
```

Note you have to make sure you add the necessary css for the plugin, either save it in the theme css folder and call it my_extra.css or change the code above to suit loading the css from an external web page.